# .group not returning all columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a .group query that is not returning all the columns in the select and I was wondering if someone could validate my syntax. 
Here is a query with a .group and the result from my console;

```
Expense.select('account_number, SUM(credit_amount)').group(:account_number).first
Expense Load (548.8ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) account_number, SUM(credit_amount) FROM [expenses] GROUP BY account_number'
       (36.9ms)  SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.views
```

Even though I select two columns, I'm only getting the first one to return.  I'm wondering if I may be dealing with an db adapter problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SUM(credit_amount)` column from the SQL has no alias and will not have a column name by default.  If you change it to have an alias `SUM(credit_amount) As 'A'` for example and select the alias name, it should pick it up.

Comment: `>> Expense.select("account_number, SUM(credit_amount) As 'A'").group(:account_number).first
  Expense Load (600.2ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) account_number, SUM(credit_amount) As ''A'' FROM [expenses] GROUP BY account_number'
#<Expense account_number: "9190-611-00M173">
   (27.2ms)  SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.views`

Tried adding the alias and still just one column returns.

Comment: Got it.  
After adding the alias and using `puts` to check the results, it's working! 
The thing that confused me is the console doesn't show the full results, only the none aggregated results. Go figure... 

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try giving your sum an alias:

```
expense = Expense.select('account_number, SUM(credit_amount) AS credit_amount').group(:account_number).first
puts expense.credit_amount
```

ActiveRecord doesn't create a default alias for aggregation operations such as `SUM`, `COUNT` etc... you have to do it explicitly to be able to access the results, as shown above.

Comment: Thanks Leonard, but I tried adding the alias and still only one column.

Comment: So if you run the exact code above in the terminal, what sort of exception do you get?

Comment: I just had this problem and can confirm that if you alias the column, the column still won't be shown unless you explicitly `puts` the column name. For example, if I have a query called `@results` that contains `SELECT jobs.type, COUNT(DISTINCT(places.name)) AS visits` I have to `@results.first.visits` to see the result output like `673`. Otherwise `@results` just outputs the unaliased columns like `puts @result.first.inspect
#<Job id: nil, type: "fix toilet"`